# OpenLayers - HTML DIV overlay

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to display a map on a standard HTML page, and I want to create a div that sits on top of the map. However, the div always seems to be obscured by the map tiles.

I believe there is a way to add elements to the map itself, but in this case that isn't a viable option since the div will potentially float partially over the map, and partially over other page elements.

```html
<div id="maphost" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
<div id="overlay" />
```

That is the basic HTML. What CSS values do I need to add to either DIV to make this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add a z-index

```html
<div id="maphost" style="width:100%; height:100%; z-index: 0"></div>
<div id="overlay" style="z-index:9999"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: Scratch that, yes it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another internal method for doing it is to use this css:

```
div.olMapViewport {
     z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Both answers +1 as they work great. Personally I prefer this one. BTW do you guys, the_skua or @ilia choly, have any idea where does the viewport takes/gets its `z-index` set to something greater than 0, as div.olMap has `z-index`set to 0?

Comment: Don't know. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: This is not a safe solution as if the zIndex is defined in javascript by OpenLayers now or in the future, the css will be ignored...

Answer (score 0):

edit this as needed

```
  <div id="search" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; padding: 5px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search photos by tag(s)" style="width: 200px">
  <button type="button">Search</button>
```

Comment: Please explain why and how this will solve the issue